# cmake _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL and RuntimeLibrary mismatch detected

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake

I am learning to build library with the following command

```
cmake -S . -B .\build\ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
cmake --build .\build\
```

I am getting the following errors during `cmake --build .\build\`

```
error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in main.obj
```

I was referring the question at the [error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668200/error-lnk2038-mismatch-detected-for-iterator-debug-level-value-0-doesnt) to solve the error `error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj` but would like to know how to implement their solution using cmake.
 I referred the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62792692/6319901) to solve the problem but it didn't solve the error.

Second problem is that I can't understand why `MD_DynamicRelease` is being built even though I added the option `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`.

---

**Root CMakeLists.txt File**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(CppProjectTemplate VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)


set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD              17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED     ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS            OFF)

set(MY_LIBRARY_NAME Library)


#Chapter 22 Starts Here --> Needs to be a cmake project else can't be used
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
    nlohmann_json # Must be the same name as mentioned in the main (root) cmake project file
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/nlohmann/json
    GIT_TAG v3.11.2
    GIT_SHALLOW TRUE #Won't clone recurrsively
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(nlohmann_json)# Must be the same name as mentioned in the main (root) cmake project file

FetchContent_Declare(
    fmt # Must be the same name as mentioned in the main (root) cmake project file
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt
    GIT_TAG 9.1.0
    GIT_SHALLOW TRUE #Won't clone recurrsively
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(fmt)# Must be the same name as mentioned in the main (root) cmake project file

FetchContent_Declare(
    spdlog # Must be the same name as mentioned in the main (root) cmake project file
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/gabime/spdlog
    GIT_TAG v1.11.0
    GIT_SHALLOW TRUE #Won't clone recurrsively
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(spdlog)# Must be the same name as mentioned in the main (root) cmake project file

FetchContent_Declare(
    cxxopts # Must be the same name as mentioned in the main (root) cmake project file
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/jarro2783/cxxopts
    GIT_TAG v3.0.0
    GIT_SHALLOW TRUE #Won't clone recurrsively
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(cxxopts)# Must be the same name as mentioned in the main (root) cmake project file

FetchContent_Declare(
    Catch2 # Must be the same name as mentioned in the main (root) cmake project file
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2
    GIT_TAG v2.13.9
    GIT_SHALLOW TRUE #Won't clone recurrsively
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(Catch2)# Must be the same name as mentioned in the main (root) cmake project file
# Chapter 22 Ends Here
# Enable/Disable option using -D<Option-Name>=1 or 0 e.g. -DCOMPILE_EXECUTABLE=1
option(COMPILE_EXECUTABLE "Whether to compile the executable" ON) 

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

---

**src folder**

my_lib.hh

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdint>
void print_hello_world(void);
std::uint32_t factorial(std::uint32_t number);
```

my_lib.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include "my_lib.hh"
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>
#include <cxxopts.hpp>

/**
 * @brief Print out Hello, World!!! and print the version of nlohmann-json, fmt-format, cxxopts and spdlog library
 * 
 */
void print_hello_world(void)
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!!!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Json Lib Version (Inside print_hello_world) : "   
        << NLOHMANN_JSON_VERSION_MAJOR << "."
        << NLOHMANN_JSON_VERSION_MINOR << "."
        << NLOHMANN_JSON_VERSION_PATCH << std::endl;

    std::cout << "FMT Version (Inside print_hello_world) : "    
        << FMT_VERSION << std::endl;

    std::cout << "cxxopts Version (Inside print_hello_world) : "    
        << CXXOPTS__VERSION_MAJOR << "."
        << CXXOPTS__VERSION_MINOR << "."
        << CXXOPTS__VERSION_PATCH << std::endl;

    std::cout << "spdlogs Version (Inside print_hello_world) : "    
        << SPDLOG_VER_MAJOR << "."
        << SPDLOG_VER_MINOR << "."
        << SPDLOG_VER_PATCH << std::endl;
}

std::uint32_t factorial(std::uint32_t number)
{
    return number <= 1 ? number : factorial(number-1) * number;
}
```

src CMakeLists.txt

```
set(
    LIBRARY_SOURCES 
    "my_lib.cc"
    )

set(LIBRARY_HEADERS 
    "my_lib.hh")

add_library(${MY_LIBRARY_NAME} STATIC ${LIBRARY_SOURCES} ${LIBRARY_HEADERS})

target_include_directories(${MY_LIBRARY_NAME} PUBLIC 
    "./"
    "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/configured_files/include"
)

target_link_libraries(${MY_LIBRARY_NAME} PUBLIC 
    nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json
    cxxopts::cxxopts
    fmt::fmt
    spdlog::spdlog
)
```

---

**Test Directory**

CMakeLists.txt

```
set(TEST_PROJECT "TestExecutable")
set(TEST_SOURCES "main.cc")
set(TEST_INCLUDE "./")

add_executable(${TEST_PROJECT} ${TEST_SOURCES})
target_include_directories(${TEST_PROJECT} PUBLIC ${TEST_INCLUDE})
target_link_libraries(${TEST_PROJECT} PUBLIC ${MY_LIBRARY_NAME} Catch2::Catch2)
```

main.cc

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN

#include "catch.hpp"
#include "my_lib.hh"

TEST_CASE("Factorial are computed", "[Factorial]")
{
    REQUIRE(factorial(1) == 1);
    REQUIRE(factorial(2) == 2);
    REQUIRE(factorial(3) == 6);
    REQUIRE(factorial(10) == 3628800);
}
```

Comment: When build the project with Visual Studio generator, build type isn't known at configuration stage, when `cmake -S <..> -B <..>` is run and when `CMakeLists.txt` is processed. Setting `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` with such generator is at least useless and could confuse other projects which you use as subprojects. With Visual Studio build type is specified with `--config` option to `cmake --build` invocation.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I tried the following command but still getting the same error
`cmake -S . -B build\ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` and `cmake --build .\build\ --config Debug`

Comment: Do not use `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` option at all. And make clean configuration (with empty build directory).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Tried all permutation and combinations. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @DarkSorrow is this happening in the `test` project?

Comment: @MilanŠ., Yes this is happening in the `test` project and especially while linking `Catch2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your reply to my comment the issue is in this line:

```
target_link_libraries(${TEST_PROJECT} PUBLIC ${MY_LIBRARY_NAME} Catch2::Catch2)
```

I've faced similar issues and it's caused by not linking the `debug` library of Catch2 in `DEBUG` builds (but instead the `release` libraries). To fix this you need to use **generator expressions** for linking `Catch2`. I do not have a concrete example (it's been years since I've used Catch2), but you ideally need to link the actual `Catch2` library without using the alias `Catch2::Catch2` and use [generator expressions to specify the debug library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html). e.g. you need something like:

```
target_link_libraries(${TEST_PROJECT} PUBLIC ${MY_LIBRARY_NAME} Catch2<$<$CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:DEBUG>d>)
```

Where Catch2 is the actual library target and not the **alias** i.e. `Catch2::Catch2`. The generator expression basically expands to `Catch2d` when `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE == DEBUG`.

---

EDIT: As DarkSorrow mentions in the comments below, this has resolved the issue for him

```
target_link_libraries(${TEST_PROJECT} PUBLIC ${MY_LIBRARY_NAME} Catch2$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:d>)
```

Comment: I used the following command `target_link_libraries(${TEST_PROJECT} PUBLIC ${MY_LIBRARY_NAME} Catch2$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:d>)` to build the library,

Comment: @DarkSorrow Will put an edit to the answer to include it for other people. Glad it's fixed.